# Not able to connect to azure postgres db from azure data factory when SSL is enabled

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-postgresql

**I'm new to Azure Data factory and i'm trying to create data set that connects to azure postgres db where SSL is enabled, but i get the below error, any idea how to solve this error without disabling SSL on postgres.**

[image]

**when i try to add sslmode=Allow to connection parameters, i get this error**

[image]

Comment: set ssl mode to required, not allowed. set min ssl to tls 1.2 on pg side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select EncryptionMethod option in link service. As [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-postgresql) shows,
[image]

[image]

---

Update:

I haven't met your error. I can connect successfully via integration run time.
The following is my setting, you can have a try.

In Azure Database for PostgreSQL:
[image]

Link service:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response , i did this and created private endpoint as well as custom integration run time, and now i'm getting time out errors

Comment: @user2249979 I updated my answer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: I have different  configuration for Azure Database for PostgreSQL, where public access is denied